# C# how can I open a box to update the user on progress?

Tags: c#, window

I want to open a window that will display some text like "Validating input" and hold it open until a method is finished. I can't do this with messagebox. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Is this during some long running operation?

Comment: No it's pretty quick. But I need this box to stay there while it runs so that the user won't leave their seat because the method MAY require some input.

Comment: You can open a modal dialog box via ShowDialog() with a progress bar in it, and close it once the method has finished. If the method takes long then you could even run it in a different thread and still have the dialog box open running with a progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood this sounds a tad cruel to the user, but you *could* do something like this:

A `MessageBox` is just a standard Windows Form shown as a modal dialog.  If you don't like the controls displayed on the form then you can create your own form and show it to the user as a modal dialog through the [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method:

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialig.ShowDialog();
```

Your `MyDialog` form can then either perform the validation itself, or respond to notification that the validation has completed.  Until the dialog has been dismissed the user won't be able to interact with the rest of the app (just as when a message box is shown) and the dialog could even disable buttons / prevent the user from closing it until the validation has succeeded.

If you do this and your modal dialog isn't performing the validation then you should be aware that you will need to perform the validation on a background thread, as the UI thread will be tied up displaying the modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a basic form, and do something like this.

```
this.Enabled = false;
FormWaiting frm = new FormWaiting();
frm.Show();

Thread.Sleep(1000000); //Place holder for long operation.
frm.Close();
this.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: I wouldn't? But that's what Joey G wants. Don't know why?

Comment: @bemused I think `Thread.Sleep` is a placeholder for the expensive operation. But the problem with this code is that a window should a working message loop.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your app context you can pick up example of @Jethro, or

Create a your `FormWaiting:Form` , make it **topmost** and call `Show()`, one time your method finished execution close it.

There is a lot other stuff that you can do, but depends on yuor concrete context which can not be very clear from the post.

Hope this helps.

Regards.